# Calculate Average for the month in SQlite

Tags: sqlite

I have an Sqlite table as below called balance history:

Table Balance History

```
Date                  Amount
2013-11-01 16:26:52   1000
2013-11-15 13:20:52   2000
2013-11-27 12:26:55   3000
```

I would like to calculate the average for the month.

**

- The Expected OutPut will be 1666.67

**
Which will be (1000 * 14 days + 2000 * 12 days + 3000 * 4 days)/30 days
= (14000 + 24000 + 12000)/30 = 1666.67

How can I achieve this in SQlite? any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary to use a date format that is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)?

Comment: Thanks, CL I just put the dates as an example. I am using the correct date format in the actual table. but, how can I get the mentioned logic to calculate the average in sqlite?

Comment: Does your table contain data for only one month?

Comment: Nope, Data is there for the full year, but I need to calculate the average on a monthly basis only. So it can be any month but average for the month only. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to show correct example data.

Comment: Idea is to get the average for the month. if some one can explain the same for any particular month. then I can work on it? I hope the question is clear in that sense.

Comment: Can you please advice me what changes needs to be made in the question. thanks appreciate your help

Comment: 1. Use correct date format 2. show more than one month 3. show the desired output.

Comment: I have considered the 1st and 3rd points. Lets assume my data is only for one month, hence ignored the 2nd point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to compute the start and the end of each interval.

The simple query (`SELECT Date AS "From", Amount FROM BalanceHistory WHERE Date GLOB '2013-11*'`) gets the start for each interval in the month.
(`GLOB` is case sensitive and thus allows to use a normal index; `LIKE` would require a special case-insensitive index.)

If there is no record for the first day of the month, the part after the `UNION ALL` adds the last record of the previous month and changes the day to the 1st.

The `COALESCE` computes the end of the interval.
The subquery gets the next date from the table, if there is one in the current month.
If there is no such record, it takes the first day of the next month:

```
SELECT date("From") AS "From",
       COALESCE((SELECT date(MIN(Date))
                 FROM BalanceHistory
                 WHERE Date > "From"
                   AND Date GLOB '2013-11*'),
                date('2013-11-01', '+1 month')
               ) AS "To",
       "Amount"
FROM (SELECT Date AS "From",
             Amount
      FROM BalanceHistory
      WHERE Date GLOB '2013-11*'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT date(Date, '+1 month', 'start of month'),
                   Amount
            FROM BalanceHistory
            WHERE Date < '2013-11'
              AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM BalanceHistory
                              WHERE Date GLOB '2013-11-01*')
            ORDER BY Date DESC
            LIMIT 1)
     );
From        To          Amount    
----------  ----------  ------
2013-11-01  2013-11-15  1000
2013-11-15  2013-11-27  2000
2013-11-27  2013-12-01  3000
```

We can then wrap this in another query to compute the number of days, and add them up.
The `strftime` calculates the last day of the month, i.e., the number of days:

```
SELECT SUM((julianday("To") - julianday("From")) * Amount) /
       strftime('%d', '2013-11-01', '+1 month', '-1 day') AS MonthAvg
FROM (SELECT date("From") AS "From",
             COALESCE((SELECT date(MIN(Date))
                       FROM BalanceHistory
                       WHERE Date > "From"
                         AND Date GLOB '2013-11*'),
                      date('2013-11-01', '+1 month')
                     ) AS "To",
             "Amount"
      FROM (SELECT Date AS "From",
                   Amount
            FROM BalanceHistory
            WHERE Date GLOB '2013-11*'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT date(Date, '+1 month', 'start of month'),
                         Amount
                  FROM BalanceHistory
                  WHERE Date < '2013-11'
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM BalanceHistory
                                    WHERE Date GLOB '2013-11-01*')
                  ORDER BY Date DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
           )
     )
```

And while we're at it, we can wrap this in yet another query to replace all those `2013-11` strings with the month as read from the table.
This allows as to compute this for every month:

```
SELECT Month,
       (SELECT SUM((julianday("To") - julianday("From")) * Amount) /
               strftime('%d', Month || '-01', '+1 month', '-1 day')
        FROM (SELECT date("From") AS "From",
                     COALESCE((SELECT date(MIN(Date))
                               FROM BalanceHistory
                               WHERE Date > "From"
                                 AND Date GLOB Month || '*'),
                              date(Month || '-01', '+1 month')
                             ) AS "To",
                     "Amount"
              FROM (SELECT Date AS "From",
                           Amount
                    FROM BalanceHistory
                    WHERE Date GLOB Month || '*'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (SELECT date(Date, '+1 month', 'start of month'),
                                 Amount
                          FROM BalanceHistory
                          WHERE Date < Month
                            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                            FROM BalanceHistory
                                            WHERE Date GLOB Month || '-01*')
                          ORDER BY Date DESC
                          LIMIT 1)
                   )
             )
       ) AS MonthAvg
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y-%m', Date) AS Month
      FROM BalanceHistory)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you, CL for the prompt response. Will go through this today and will get back to you if I have any queries. Otherwise will surely mark this as the answer. Again Thanks a lot for your time.